# What is the merit of introducing static methods in interface over introducing final methods(if there was one) in java 8?

Tags: java

I read from some source as 'Java interface static method helps us in providing security by not allowing implementation classes to override them'.(We can hide them though!)

Even final methods can not be overridden. My doubt is 'why did not Java introduce final methods instead of static methods?' . What is that static methods offering over final methods?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot have a `final` method in an interface. A `final` method cannot be overridden. The instance methods in an interface *must* be overridden by the implemented class. So it would make no sense. A `static` method also cannot be overridden, but only because it is not inherited; it is not an instance method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static methods are invoked using the interface name and can be hidden in derived classes. Final methods are a class specific construct (so far) and cannot be hidden or overridden. They are invoked using an instance name. If you define a method in an interface as final and not static, how would you invoke it? By definition, you cannot create an instance of the interface?

See Brian Goetz's comment [here][2]

And see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233053/why-were-default-and-static-methods-added-to-interfaces-in-java-8-when-we-alread) for reason to add static and default methods.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between static and non-static contexts is what you want to focus on.  "static" is a memory space that exists once, and is shared by all instances of a given class.  "final" simply defines the item so it can not be changed, but it can still be static/non-static.

Comment: `final` doesn't prevent an object from being changed. It prevents it from being reassigned. In case of a class or method, it prevents it from being extended.

Comment: Agreed.... I just guess I was lazy on the details of "change" :)